# Share Core Data database between app and today extension in Swift

Tags: ios, widget

I have a database from which my widget has to read some data. I've set the membership targets to all the related files to both the app and the widget. There is a problem though.

I have a helper class **in my main app** that gets the AppDelegate context whenever i do some operations on the database. The code looks as follows:

```
class func getEntityAndContext(name:String) -> (entity:NSEntityDescription, context: NSManagedObjectContext){
    var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let entity:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(name, inManagedObjectContext: context)!
    return (entity, context)
}
```

This method helps me in cases like these:

```
class func getAll() -> Array<City>{
        let (_, context) = NSManagedObjectWrapper.getEntityAndContext("City")
        let req = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "City")
        req.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)]
        let citiesList:Array<City> = context.executeFetchRequest(req, error: nil)! as Array<City>
        return citiesList
    }
```

After i added the target membership to the widget, i get this error: `Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'`. It makes sense, but i have no idea how to fix it. Can you please help me?

PS: I also noticed that i get this error too: `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSFetchRequest'`. What am i doing wrong? This surely can't be the way to do it...

Comment: Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer here:
https://github.com/pjchavarria/Swift-Widget

This git project shows how to use core data in a widget.

Comment: I tried that example but I get 'Cannot create an SQL store with a nil URL.'